# How to add active state to CMS Page in Top Menu?

Tags: magento-1.9, navigation, topmenu

How to add active state to CMS Page in Top Menu?
I get active class if i'm on category page.
I'm add items to Top Navigation used categories rewrites urls in magento.

I need help.

Comment: can  you please give me screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the proper way to add a cms page link to the main menu without using the event `page_block_html_topmenu_gethtml_before`.
This way you will be able to add an active state to it also.
[So create an observer](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method) in one of your modules that can look like this:

```
public function addCmsPage($observer) 
{
    //your page identifier
    $cmsPageIdentifier = 'page_idendifier_here';
    //get the menu instance
    $menu = $observer->getMenu();
    //load the page
    $page = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->load($cmsPageIdentifier, $identifier);
    //if the page exists
    if ($page->getId()) {
        $active = false;
        // Get the full action name for the request.
        $fullActionName = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->getFullActionName();
        //check if we are on the view page action for the required page
        if ($fullActionName == 'cms_page_view') {
             $pageId = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('page_id', $this->getRequest()->getParam('id', false)); 
             if ($pageId == $page->getId()) {
                 $active = true;
             }
        }
        //build a new menu item node
        $data = array(
            'name' => $page->getTitle(),
            'id' => 'cms-'.$cmsPageIdentifier,
            'url' => Mage::getUrl('', array('_direct'=>$cmsPageIdentifier)),
            'is_active' => $active
        );
        $pageNode = new Varien_Data_Tree_Node($data, 'id', $tree, $menu);
        //attach the node to the menu
        $menu->addChild($pageNode);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add this code after to *$menu* on topmenu file.**

```
<?php
$urlkey = 'contactus;aboutus;team'; // Define a identifier cms pages using ';'
$arrayUrlKey = explode(";", $urlkey);
foreach($arrayUrlKey as $url){
    $condition = explode(':', $url);
    $page = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->load($condition[0], 'identifier');
    if($condition[1]) $class = 'menu-item-'.$condition[1];
    if($page->getIsActive()) {
?> 
    <li class="level0 level-top parent custom-block <?php if($routeName == 'cms' && $identifier == $page->getIdentifier()) {echo " active";}?> <?php echo $class;?>">
        <a href="<?php echo Mage::helper('cms/page')->getPageUrl($condition[0]);?>" class="level-top">
            <span><?php echo $page->getTitle();?></span>
        </a> 
    </li> 
<?php 
    }
}
?>
```